# Bypass & Enable tether / WiFi hotspot on Android M (Marshmallow) Preview 3?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, tethering, wifi-tethering, 6.0-marshmallow, developer-preview

I just got a Nexus 6 and flashed Android M Preview 3 to it and also have it rooted, but how do I enable tethering / WiFi hotspot?

I tried doing the old method of finding `dun_tether` in the SQLite database, but it isn't there anymore.

How would one enable tethering / WiFi hotspot on Android M (Marshmallow)?

Comment: that solution does not work on android m preview 3 -- i get this error: Tethering or Hotspot Error -- Unable to connect to data network; You may not be subscribed to Tethering or Hotspot service; please contact your phone company.

Comment: I just realized you're the OP and the answerer, sorry. Anyway, please add your comment to this post to counter the dupe. Otherwise, we don't know there's a difference between Dev Preview 3 and the older.

Comment: I'll update it on the other question. as i resolved it. i'll post an answer there.

Comment: One thing to note is that it is just a developer preview so it might not be coded in. Also with the release just about a week way google could be pulling parts to merge with the final source code.